# handling of argument objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arguments

attempting to create a function that will return an array with the first n elements of a given array. It must have the following handling:

- should return an array with the first n elements of the array
- should return an array with the first element if n is not a number, is zero, or negative
- should return the entire array if n is > length
- should work on an arguments object
- should return an empty array if array is not an array

I'm having trouble satisfying the "should work on an arguments object" while using the following code. When I add a line of code to convert the arguments object into an array then it raises an error with "should return an empty array if array is not an array" - because we're automatically converting the argument into an array. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
_.first = function (array, n) {
  
  array = Array.from(array);   
     
  if (!Array.isArray(array)) return [];
  
  if (isNaN(n) || n <= 0) return [array[0]];
  
  if (array.length - 1 < n) return array;
  
  return array.slice(0, n);
   
};
```

Comment: I guess it's some sort of homework? Sounds like the issue is the task is unclear rarher than a coding problem.

Comment: prework for a bootcamp and I feel ridiculous not being able to get it figured out haha

Comment: Based on your description it does sound contradicting, but pheraps the original wording is clearer

Comment: unfortunately I copy and pasted the prompt for the most part. but im glad to know it feels confusing to someone else too haha

Comment: Perhaps they are asking you to work with the function's argument object?  In which case you would not define the parameters in the function (`function (array, n) {}`), rather you would define `array` and `n` variables from the arguments object like `function() { var array = Array.from(arguments[0]); var n = arguments[1]; ... }`

Comment: I think it may be that they're asking to work with the functions argument object as well. But in one of the check cases they use, they're passing an argument object into array and passing a number into n